# Relationship between rank and Eigen values....

Tags: matrices

If the Eigen values of 3 matrices are 1)0,2,4    2)5,6,7   3)0,2,2.
 Then what are their respective rank of the matrices

Comment: The rank of a square matrix is its dimension minus the number of 0 eigenvalues.  Who ever gave you this problem expected you to know that.

Comment: $Ax = \lambda x$ holds for eigenvalue $\lambda$. Consider the case $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix of full rank is invertible and thus also bijective; *a fortiori* only the zero vector is mapped to the zero vector. This implies a matrix of full rank cannot have a zero eigenvalue (*why?*).

For the more general result, do you know the **rank-nullity theorem**? For a square matrix of size $n$, the sum of the *rank* and the *nullity* is $n$. You're interested in the rank and the nullity is precisely the dimension of the kernel of the matrix, so of all vectors satisfying... Can you finish?